# The problem of redirect in Apache Superset

Tags: apache-superset

When changing the language in the superset, a redirect to the main page occurs.

How to fix this problem so that the redirect does not occur?

Answer (score 0):

How do you changing the language? Do you modify the following contents in config.py?

## Setup default language

BABEL_DEFAULT_LOCALE = "zh"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).